# Prove that the largest number of $1$'s in the $n\times n$ invertible matrix $A$ with entries $0$ or $1$ is $n^2-n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Prove that the largest number of $1$'s in the $n\times n$ invertible matrix $A$ with entries $0$ or $1$ is $n^2-n+1$.

My approach. If we denote $M=$number of $1$ in $A$ and $N=$number of $0$ . Then $M+N=n^2$. We are required to prove $M\leq n^2-n+1 $ alternatively $N\geq n-1$.

Assume $n-1 >N$.

Claim 1: There will be at least one column with all entries $1$.

Proof: There are $n$ columns and if each were to contain at least one $0$ then number of $N\geq n$. Contrary to assumption that $n-1>N$. Proved.

Place this column with all entries $1$ in the first column. This can always be done by column interchange without affecting the invertiblity of $A$.

Claim 2: Now there will be a second column with at most one $0$.

Proof: As we already selected the first column we are left with $n-1$ columns. If all of them contains more than one 0 then there will be more than $n-1$ zero contradicting the assumption again.

Now place this column to second column.

Now two things can happen to second column.

As this column contains at  most one $0$ either

**(1)** The second column contains all $1$

**(2)** The second column contains exactly one $0$ and $n-1$ numbers of $1$ .

In **(1)** We have 1st and 2nd column equal . So their Determinant $0$.

**(2)** $1$st column contains all $1$ and $2$nd column contains exactly one zero. Wlog assume this zero is in the first row. (This can be achieved by row interchange.)
Now the 1st columns contains all 1 and second column contains $0$ in the first component ad rest are all $1$.

Now subtract $2$nd column from $1$st column in the 1st column. This will leave the $1$st column with $1$ in the $(1,1)$ position of the matrix and all entries $0$. Now expand by coffactors. We see that required deteminant is now equal to a determinant of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ whose all entries in the $1$st column equal to $1$. Now we are back to again where we started. If one keeps doing this we eventually reach determinant $0$.
Hence proved.

This how i proved it. I'm sure about the correctness of **(1)** but not so much about **(2)**. So i would like to hear your opinion about it. If you have any other proof please provide it. Thank you.

Comment: If there are fewer then $n-1$ zeroes, then there are at least _two_ rows (not just one) that are all 1s (by the pigeonhole principle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose there are $n^2-n+2$ ones and $n-2$ zeros in your matrix. Then, note that you have to distribute $n-2$ zeros among $n$ rows. By pigeonhole principle (or a variation), you get that at least two rows must be filled with ones completely. This causes the determinant to be zero, as those two rows would be the same. A similar logic follows if you had $n-k$ zeros, for $n \geq k \geq 2$.

Also, you have not answered why the maximum is *exactly* $n^2-n+1$. To see this, consider the following $n \times n$ matrix:
$$
a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & j=n \\
0 & j\neq n, i= j \\
1 & j \neq n, i \neq j 
\end{cases}
$$
For example, this matrix, in case of $n=3$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1&1 \\
1 & 0 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can see that all rows are linearly independent, hence the determinant of this matrix is non-zero (in the above case, it is $1$), and I think in all cases it will be $1$.